# H1B worker in United states, what documents are required "Evidence of family members remaining in your home country whilst you travel." uk visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, family, h1b-visas

I am Indian citizen, living in USA on H1B work visa.
My whole family is in India, I am living alone in United States.
I am applying for UK standard visitor visa short stay.
What documents should I provide "Evidence of family members remaining in your home country whilst you travel." checklist?

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't have any family members remaining at home while you travel, there's no documentation about that you need to remember to include.

That completes your consideration of that item on the checklist. Onward to the next!

(The checklist is not a list of documents that every application must contain. It is a list of things you don't want to forget *if they happen to be relevant for your application*).